# CCA for Feature Fusion

Tags: matlab, face-recognition, pattern-recognition, feature-extraction, feature-selection

In some of the multi-modal recognition methods, they are using Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA) to fuse the two input feature vectors into a single and also a low dimension one.
Matlab has already the code for CCA which is:
[A,B,r,U,V] = canoncorr(X,Y);
See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/canoncorr.html

I wonder how I can reach the final (fused) feature vector using this function. 
Can someone explain the steps or suggest a reference, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to perform the feature fusion using CCA. I wrote a Matlab code to do it and shared the code in [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54681).

Detailed descriptions can be found in this paper:

M. Haghighat, M. Abdel-Mottaleb, W. Alhalabi, "[Fully Automatic Face Normalization and Single Sample Face Recognition in Unconstrained Environments](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2015.10.047)," Expert Systems With Applications, vol. 47, pp. 23-34, April 2016.

Comment: Could you disclose some details from the paper? I and presumably also other ones can only read the abstract.

Comment: how can i use this function for separate 2 features to combined together. it gives an error for me
[trainZ,testZ] = ccaFuse(trainX, trainY, testX, testY, 'sum');